# SSIS 2015/SQL Server 2016 : some columns values aren't loaded from AS/400

Tags: ssis, db2, oledb, sql-server-2016

We have a problem reading and loading some columns from AS/400 via OLE DB Provider for DB2 in SSIS 2015, the project is in SQL Server 2016.
We're migrating the project from an old server that is working with SQL Server 2008.
In the new one, when I preview the data in the Data Flow OLE DB Source, some columns have "System.Byte[]" as a value.
And I got the message "The metadata of the following output columns does not match thr metadata of the external columns with which the output columns are associated".
The external columns are read as DT_BYTES, while on the old server they were read as DT_STR.
The output columns are also expecting a DT_STR.

SSIS changed the metadata of the external columns, thus, making them unreadable.

I tried casting them as string, nothing works.

I tried setting the "ValidateExternalMetadata" to False, nothing.

The crazy thing is, with some other tables that have similar data types it reads them well, they have exactly the same data types as the failed ones.

There's no problem with the AS/400 itself as the old SSIS 2008 reads everything well.

So, I'm sure the problem is either with OL DB2 Provider, SSIS 2015 or SQL Server 2016.

I can't force it to read the external columns as STR with the Advanced Editor.

I also tried converting the data types in the output columns to DT_BYTES to match it, but still it didn't work.

It can't even read the columns from the beginning.

I tried a whole new package with no query, just reading the table as it is from the source, still the same problem.

I changed the Code Page to match the oiginal (1256), still nothing, then I changed it to match the new one (1252), still no success.

I'm really stuck and tried everything I could.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it!

The solution is to open the connection manager, go to "All" tab, and match the Binary Codepage value (which is 0 by default) to the Host CCSID value.

I also set up the DBMS Platform to "DB2/AS400".